# rsync listing directory with no changes

Tags: terminal, backup, bash, rsync

I have been trying to figure out this rsync behavior, where it still lists directories with different timestamps and the same sizes despite providing a `--size-only` flag.

```
# lists some directory without listing any changed files
> rsync -av [path 1] [path 2] --dry-run --size-only
> building file list ... done
> folder1/folder1a/
> folder1/folder1b/

# checks reasons with -i
# ...
> .d..t....folder1/folder1a/
> .d..t....folder1/folder1b/
```

As you can see, `--itemize-change` shows that the only difference between the source and destination folders is the timestamp. But it is still listed in my regular rsync run despite providing `--size-only`. Is there a way to fix this? It seems like it still modifies the destination folder if I were to run it, which causes a folder reupload in my cloud backup services. Thanks!

**EDIT:** rsync version is 2.6.9. Source is a folder with subfolders inside it, and inside which are random files. Destination is my OneDrive folder. It should be identical to the source, but after running rsync to transfer the folders, it seems like OneDrive touches the folders and making future rsync see them as different (and nothing else manual is happening when rsync is being run). I don't mind that, but I just don't want rsync to update them further when run in the future. Hence I add the `--size-only` flag to ignore timestamp differences. What I am trying to understand is why these dir's are still being listed, even though the change reported by `--itemize-change` is only timestamp difference (`.d..t....`)? I just don't want them to be re-transferred every time I run rsync simply because they have different timestamps.

**EDIT 2:** At first I uploaded them onto OneDrive (not w/ rsync), then ran rsync with `--size-only` on the folder later. As a result the mod time of the destination files are never changed. While `--size-only` skips over the file themselves, the folder is still seen as "different". So I think that even though the only difference on the folders itself is timestamp (`.d..t....`), it still updates the folder as the files inside are perceived to be different (even with `--size-only`). Once I rsync'd everything without `--size-only` one time, the problem disappeared since the mod time of files inside have changed.

But this behavior is undesirable, since the folder and the files themselves are identical aside from timestamps, so `--size-only` should ignore the folder altogether. I am only intending to use rsync to fill missed files after uploading onto OneDrive (web), and not rsync them from the get-go (as sometimes syncing changes from local drive with OneDrive is very very slow compared to uploading). Is there a way around this? How can I stop rsync from updating directories whose contents are identical size-wise?

Comment: What version of rsync?

Comment: If you want a clear answer, please clarify your question. What is the source? What is the destination? Is *anything* happening to your source & destination between runs of rsync?

Comment: @Seamus added edit to clarify the problem

Comment: That's much better thanks. Don't have time for an answer now, but will get back to you. In the meantime, you may be interested in this [*recipe*](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/RsyncWithNoMetaDataLoss.md) I posted on GitHub recently. In particular, there is a procedure with a couple of scripts to compare your source to your destination.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the info. I added some edit to the question as I narrowed down on what my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rsync` command you're using: `rsync -av ...`

If you refer to `man rsync`, note the following:

> -a, --archive               archive mode; same as -rlptgoD (no -H)

In other words: `-a` implies the options: `-rlptgoD`

Note that option `-t` is defined in `man rsync` as follows:

> -t, --times                 preserve time

Now, for the `--size-only` option, `man rsync` tells us:

> --size-only
> Normally rsync will not transfer any files that are already the same size and  have  the  same  modification time-stamp.  With  the --size-only option, files will not be transferred if they have the same size, regard-less of timestamp. This is useful when starting to use rsync after using another mirroring system which may not preserve timestamps exactly.

I have not had time to verify this (I'll let you do that if you don't mind), but what I think this means is that while no file is being transferred (it's a folder) due to `--size-only`, the `-t` option (implied with `-a`) is causing the folder's time stamp (modification time) is being updated by `rsync`. You can verify that by changing the `rsync` command you're using to:

```
rsync -rlpgoDv --dry-run --size-only [path 1] [path 2] --dry-run --size-only
```

Note there are two (2) changes here; one to eliminate the (implied) `-t` option, the other to place **all** options prior to the Source & Destination locations to correspond with the command syntax under `SYNOPSIS` in `man rsync`. Also, I seem to *vaguely recall* reading somewhere that misplacing options in `rsync` created issues.

To reiterate some of the comments:

- See [the table](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/RsyncWithNoMetaDataLoss.md#decoding-the-itemize-output-option-i) at the bottom of the GitHub recipe to help decode the `-i` output.
- The recipe also contains a procedure & script you may consider using to verify you are getting *exactly* what you want; the [`get-stats.sh` script](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/src/get-stats.sh) - or simply using the `stat` command selectively - will allow you to verify the time-stamps.
- If you're using ver 2.6.9 of `rsync`, you should probably invest some time to upgrade to a current version. I recommend MacPorts for this. If you have any detailed questions on how to go about that, those are probably best handled under a new question.

Comment: you are right, removing the implied `-t` changed everything

Comment: Note also that `-v` implies a bunch of progress reporting options. Check `man rsync` and look for the `--info` flag to replace `-v` with a narrower list of options for reporting.